# Bootstrap offcanvas height to content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

```css
.cursor-pointer {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.4.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button class="btn btn-primary m-2" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#offcanvasBottom" aria-controls="offcanvasBottom">Toggle bottom offcanvas</button>
<div class="offcanvas offcanvas-bottom" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvasBottom" aria-labelledby="offcanvasBottomLabel">
  <div class="offcanvas-body p-0 h-50">
    <ul class="list-unstyled m-0 fs-5">
      <li class="bg-danger text-light px-3 py-2">
        <i class="bi bi-trash"></i>
        Delete
      </li>
      <li class="bg-primary text-light px-3 py-2">
        <i class="bi bi-pin"></i>
        Pin
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I fit a height to content in my code?
I tried `d-inline` and `h-50` but nothing is working. any help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add `h-auto` to `offcanvas` element.

```css
.cursor-pointer {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.4.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button class="btn btn-primary m-2" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#offcanvasBottom" aria-controls="offcanvasBottom">Toggle bottom offcanvas</button>
<div class="offcanvas offcanvas-bottom h-auto" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvasBottom" aria-labelledby="offcanvasBottomLabel">
  <div class="offcanvas-body p-0 h-50">
    <ul class="list-unstyled m-0 fs-5">
      <li class="bg-danger text-light px-3 py-2">
        <i class="bi bi-trash"></i>
        Delete
      </li>
      <li class="bg-primary text-light px-3 py-2">
        <i class="bi bi-pin"></i>
        Pin
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.offcanvas-top.h-auto {
    bottom: initial;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.4.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button class="btn btn-primary m-2" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#offcanvasBottom" aria-controls="offcanvasBottom">Toggle bottom offcanvas</button>
<div class="offcanvas offcanvas-bottom h-auto" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvasBottom" aria-labelledby="offcanvasBottomLabel">
  <div class="offcanvas-body p-0">
    <ul class="list-unstyled m-0 fs-5">
      <li class="bg-danger text-light px-3 py-2">
        <i class="bi bi-trash"></i>
        Delete
      </li>
      <li class="bg-primary text-light px-3 py-2">
        <i class="bi bi-pin"></i>
        Pin
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

No need for the height to be set on the `.offcanvas-body`, just need to kill the `bottom:0` on the `offcanvas`.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.offcanvas {
  bottom: initial;
 }
```

Setting offcanvas class bottom initial solve mine. Thanks to @Kevin Welsh

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32315651)

Answer (score 0):

I had to set flex-grow: 0; to overwrite it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).